# Generate a new variable based on the minimal value of another variable under some conditions

Tags: r, variables

I have a dataset look like below:

```
ID year disease  
1   2007  0       
1   2008  1     
1   2009  1    
2   2008  0     
2   2009  0    
2   2010  1
```

I want to create a new variable "StartYear" recording the first time IDs started to have this disease.
my goal data looks like this:

```
ID year disease StartYear 
1   2007  0    2008    
1   2008  1    2008 
1   2009  1    2008
2   2008  0    2010 
2   2009  0    2010
2   2010  1    2010
```

So far, I know i need to use library(dplyr) and I tried this but it is not correct

```
data <- data%>%
          group_by(id)%>%
          arrange(id, year)%>%
          mutate(StartYear=ifelse(disease==1,Year,NA)
```

Comment: Just `df %>% group_by(ID) %>% mutate(Start_Year = first(year[disease == 1]))`

Comment: Or `df %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  mutate(StartYear = year[which.max(disease == 1)])`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
data %>%
        arrange(ID, year) %>%
        group_by(ID) %>%
        mutate(StartYear = year[disease == 1][1])
```

Comment: Need to make sure your rows are in the right order for this to work

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
library(tidyverse)

data %>%
group_by(ID) %>%
mutate( StartYear=min(year*(1/disease)) ) %>%
ungroup()
```